# Recursive substitution in sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I have a sympy expression with multiple variables that need to be substituted out. The problem is that the some of the expressions to be substituted in also contain instances of variables that need to be substituted out.

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.abs import a,b, x,y

expr = a + b
replace = [[a, x+y], [b, 2*a]]

expr.subs(replace) # 2*a + x + y, I want 3*x + 3*y
```

If the replacement list is in the right order, it will apply each substitution sequentially, though in my real application I don't know what order would be appropriate:

```
expr.subs(reversed(replace)) # 3*x + 3*y
```

I can force the substitution by applying the substitution n times to either `expr` or `replace`, but that seems computationally wasteful:

```
result = expr
for _ in replace:
    # Applying n times
    result = result.subs(replace)
```

I was hoping for a `recursive` option to `subs`, but that doesn't seem to exist. Any better options?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you do it in the correct order, the replacement will be performed iteratively (unless you use `subs(replacement, simultaneous=True)`, which performs all the replacements at once).

Your problem then is ordering the replacements correctly. What you want is a [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting) of the replacements. Namely, each replacement is a node in a graph, and there is an edge from `(old1, new1)` to `(old2, new2)` if `new1` contains `old2` (i.e., it should be replaced first).

SymPy has an implementation of `topological_sort` in `sympy.utilities.iterables`. It takes a list of vertices and a list of edges (tuples of vertices). Say you have

```
replace = [(y, z + 1), (x, y + z), (z, a)]
```

We can create a list of edges with

```
from itertools import combinations
edges = [(i, j) for i, j in permutations(replace, 2) if i[1].has(j[0])]
```

Sorting this gives

```
>>> from sympy import default_sort_key, topological_sort
>>> topological_sort([replace, edges], default_sort_key)
[(x, y + z), (y, z + 1), (z, a)]
```

The third argument of `topological_sort` is a key used to break ties. Since SymPy objects don't have an implicit ordering defined on them (`<` and `>` raise `TypeError` in general), there is a sort key implementation called `default_sort_key` that provides a canonical and consistent (but arbitrary) sorting of SymPy objects.

In a situation like the one shown by 404 where there would be an infinite loop, `topological_sort` will alert you that there is a cycle

```
>>> replace = [(x, y+1), (y, x+1)]
>>> edges = [(i, j) for i, j in permutations(replace, 2) if i[1].has(j[0])]
>>> topological_sort([replace, edges], default_sort_key)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<ipython-input-51-72f3bfcfd4ad>", line 1, in <module>
    topological_sort([replace, edges], default_sort_key)
  File "/Users/aaronmeurer/Documents/Python/sympy/sympy/sympy/utilities/iterables.py", line 882, in topological_sort
    raise ValueError("cycle detected")
ValueError: cycle detected
```

Honestly, this ought to just be implemented directly in `subs` via a keyword argument. See https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/6257.

Answer (score 2):

If recursive option existed, it would presumably perform the substitution until the expression stops changing. This is something you can do yourself; and I don't think this is wasteful, after all sympy is written in Python too.

Here is a function that returns the result of substitution along with its success indicator: whether the expression reached a stable form after substitutions. This will be false for substitution rules leading to an infinite loop, like `replace = [[x, y+1], [y, x+1]]`.

```
def recursive_sub(expr, replace):
    for _ in range(0, len(replace) + 1):
        new_expr = expr.subs(replace)
        if new_expr == expr:
            return new_expr, True
        else:
            expr = new_expr
    return new_expr, False
```

Now `res, _ = recursive_sub(expr, replace)` returns `3*x + 3*y` when used with your `expr` and `replace`.

Comment: Technically, it's an iterative solution, but it's the same idea.

Comment: This will hang rather than return incomplete if `replace` has infinite loops, but that's easy to change.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and it seems, currently, there still is no simple generic solution for this issue within SymPy.

Maybe my quick and easy workaround is of any help:

**Code preface**

```
import sympy
x, y = sympy.symbols("x, y")
reps = [(y, x**2), (x, 2)]
```

**Example which shows that the order of the substitutions matters**

Directly taked from the official SymPy documentation at http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/core.html#sympy.core.basic.Basic.subs

```
>>> (x + y).subs(reps)
6
>>> (x + y).subs(reversed(reps))
x**2 + 2
```

**My workaround, which works with either order of the substitutions:**

Just substitute your variables more than one time.

```
>>> (x + y).subs(100 * reps)
6
>>> (x + y).subs(reversed(100 * reps))
6
```

Obviously, this only works for a fixed "recursion depth" and I guess the unnecessary calls (on top of the ones which actually change the expression) might be very time consuming if you're working with big expressions or many substitutions.